# How to do something when Enter-key is pressed on NSButton?

Tags: macos, cocoa

Suppose there are 5 buttons on the `NSWindow`

**CREATE**

**UPDATE**

**REFRESH**

**CANCEL**

**CLOSE**

User is pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move from 1 to another `NSButton`

Suppose, the user is on **UPDATE** button and press enter then the action should be performed.

How to achieve it?

Note: Using <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> user is able to move through all the controls however while pressing <kbd>Enter/Return</kbd> on the selected control (`NSButton`) the action is not getting raised

Comment: Do you mean ENTER? Or do you mean RETURN?

Comment: I would treat `Enter` and `Return` as same. I mean on both the action should be done. @gnasher729

Comment: Consider that the ability to select UI elements like buttons via tab key depends on the setting in System Preferences.

Comment: @vadian Using `Control+F7` user is able to move through all the controls however while pressing `Enter/Return` on the selected control (`NSButton`) the action is not getting raised

Comment: Actually you would have to assign the key equivalent `return` to the selected button and detach it from the others. Or you have to create the whole event handling by yourself.

Comment: The selected button is activated by the space bar.